# Is there a classification of embeddings of SL_2  into SP_6 as  algebraic groups over Q and R respectively?  

Tags: algebraic-groups, arithmetic-geometry

Is there a classification of embeddings of SL_2 into SP_6 as algebraic groups over Q and R respectively?

see also the link:mathoverflow.net/questions/36762,

Comment: It would help to add a link to your earlier question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/36762/, since the new one asks for a further refinement.    To adapt to the groups over the rationals or reals, you probably need to exploit the existence of *integral* forms for the groups (and their Lie algebras) along with the exponential map.   

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want the Jacobson–Morozov theorem, which says that homomorphisms of the Lie algebra sl<sub>2</sub> over a field of characteristic 0 to a semisimple Lie algebra g can be classified in terms of the nilpotent elements of g. More precisely, if e, f, h, is the usual basis of sl<sub>2</sub> then you can choose the image of e to be any nilpotent element of g, and the images of f and h are then determined up to conjugation by the centralizer of e.

For details see [Jacobson's book on Lie algebras](http://books.google.com/books?isbn=9780486638324).

Comment: in the case of Q ,the homomorphisms between groups is characterized by homomorphisms between lie algebra ?


Comment: Essentially, at least for simply connected groups. Borel's book on linear algebraic groups should give the exact conditions for this. 

Comment: And is there any refenreces have explicit computation of the problem?

Comment: There has been helpful discussion of lifting of Lie algebra homomorphisms to simply connected or other groups in an earlier post: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/36481/

Comment: Assume the base field has characteristic zero. The category of representations of a semisimple Lie algebra is Tannakian, and the algebraic group attached to this category is the simply connected algebraic group with the given Lie algebra. A homomorphism of Lie algebras defines a tensor functor of the Tannakian categories, and hence a homomorphism of the corresponding simply connected algebraic groups.